# What technologies are being used for StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

My interest is in both backend and frontend technologies.
If possible some idea about hardware is also very interesting for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a big complicated site so it has a fairly complex setup but the core of is ASP.NET MVC and MS SQL Server. For a more complete look at things there was a post about it a while back on ServerFault:

- http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/02/11/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/

This has probably expanded but I'd be surprised if there have been many major tech switches.